# window.showModalDialog returnvalue is undefined in localhost but is working when deployed in server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, window, showmodaldialog

I have a very old asp.net application where we are using window.showModalDialog for popups. The return value is always undefined when running from localhost (either using visual studio 2013 or deployed in IIS 7.0) but the same code when deployed in server (2008 R2), all the popups are returning values and is working fine. I do not have any error that I can paste here.

Tried running application using ip address and localhost.

I have looked at other links where they have an opposite issue - working in localhost but return value undefined in server.

Comment: Could this be a cross-domain issue as mentioned here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/204b79bf-e1bb-465d-9009-b424e92457c6/return-value-from-showmodaldialog-undefined-when-not-testing-on-localhost?forum=iewebdevelopment - do the URIs of the modals point to the server even when you are testing locally?

Comment: PS: It seems that showModalDialog will no longer work in Chrome and Firefox at all - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Comment: Am using IE 11. I have considered the cross-domain issue but the modal dialog displays the same ip address/localhost as the application window.

Comment: I do not have IE here, but could the modal dialog happen to display the URL of the parent window by default - or does it in fact display the full URL to the modal.html (or whatever) file, i.e. http://localhost/modals/some-modal.asp?

Comment: It displays the url of modalDialog in both server and localhost.

Comment: And these are two different URLs depending on server (i.e. it does not show server's modaldialog-url when you are on localhost?)

Comment: If I understand your question correct, Yes. When i run application using localhost/app, it doesn't show any url bar. But when ip is used instead of localhost, url bar is displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172250/discussion-between-jenny-and-cjs1978).